# Pytest function testing multi-processing task queue service

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-multiprocessing

I have a task queue processing service that I'm trying to run pytest function testing on. When running it in 'production', I start this from the command line, e.g. `python main.py`.

I can't figure out how to start this task service from pytest to do function testing on it. How do I start up the service inside pytest so that I can then add a job to it and see if the job gets processed and added to the database when completed?

```
def main():
    store = "jobs"
    worker_id = 1
    # Process tasks
    task_processing[store] = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=process_tasks, args=(store, worker_id)
        )
    nanopub_processing[store].start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `from main import main; main()`?

Comment: Arrgghhh!!!  I imported main and then ran main() and skipped a level - maybe that will teach me to name things better.  Please post that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you access the `main` function correctly:

```
from main import main

def test_main():
    main()
    ...
```